# Python : Comparing file name with folder name in same directory

Tags: python

I have a folder with lot of zip files and the extracted folders for the same.
The folder has become so much clustered .

Is there any way to compare the zipped files name with the EXTRACTED folders name in the same directory ?

i want to delete the EXTRACTED folders if they have a .zip file in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it help

```
import os
import shutil

for file in os.listdir(path_to_dir):
    if os.path.isdir(file + ".zip"):
        shutil.rmtree(file)
```

Comment: `os.remove` will not delete a directory. It will throw an error.

Comment: Have you run and tested your code? In general it looks suspicious. It's very easy to get downvotes this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
import shutil
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join, isdir

directories = [d for d in listdir('./') if isdir(join('./', d))]

files = [f for f in listdir('./') if isfile(join('./', f)) and '.zip' in f]


# print(directories)
# print(files)

for d in directories:
    for f in files:
        if f == d + '.zip':
            shutil.rmtree(d)
```

Note that you need to use something like `shutil.rmtree(d)` if you directories contain subdirectories and/or files.